# color individual points separately in QScatterSeries of Qt Charts

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qchart, qchartview, qgraphicsrectitem

am trying to color each points of QScatterSeries in Qt Chart separately when we click on each points.

```
//adding scatter series
for(int i = 0; i < CLUSTERSERIESCOUNT; ++i)//3 times
   {
        m_clusterseries[i] = new QScatterSeries();
        if(m_clusterseries[i])
        {
            m_clusterseries[i]->clear();
            connect(m_clusterseries[i], &QScatterSeries::clicked, this, &RadarGraphicsView::onClickedClusterScatterObject);
            connect(m_clusterseries[i], &QScatterSeries::hovered, this, &RadarGraphicsView::onHoverClusterObject);
        }
    }

for(int seriesIndex = 0; seriesIndex < CLUSTERSERIESCOUNT; ++seriesIndex)
    {
        if(seriesIndex == 0)
        {
            m_clusterseries[0]->setMarkerShape(QScatterSeries::MarkerShapeRectangle);
            m_clusterseries[0]->setPen(Qt::SolidLine);
            m_clusterseries[0]->setBorderColor(Qt::blue);
            m_clusterseries[0]->setColor(Qt::transparent);
            m_clusterseries[0]->setName(MOVING);
            m_clusterseries[0]->setMarkerSize(7.5);

            for(int i = 0; i < m_xValuesMCluster.count(); ++i)
            {
                m_clusterseries[0]->append(QPointF(m_xValuesMCluster.at(i), m_yValuesMCluster.at(i)));
            }
        }
        else if(seriesIndex == 1)
        {
            m_clusterseries[1]->setMarkerShape(QScatterSeries::MarkerShapeRectangle);
            m_clusterseries[1]->setPen(Qt::SolidLine);
            m_clusterseries[1]->setBorderColor(Qt::yellow);
            m_clusterseries[1]->setColor(Qt::transparent);
            m_clusterseries[1]->setName(STATIONARY);
            m_clusterseries[1]->setMarkerSize(7.5);

            for(int i = 0; i < m_xValuesSCluster.count(); ++i)
            {
                m_clusterseries[1]->append(QPointF(m_xValuesSCluster.at(i), m_yValuesSCluster.at(i)));
            }
        }
        else  if(seriesIndex == 2)
        {
            m_clusterseries[2]->setMarkerShape(QScatterSeries::MarkerShapeRectangle);
            m_clusterseries[2]->setPen(Qt::SolidLine);
            m_clusterseries[2]->setBorderColor(Qt::gray);
            m_clusterseries[2]->setColor(Qt::transparent);
            m_clusterseries[2]->setName(UNKNOWN);
            m_clusterseries[2]->setMarkerSize(7.5);

            for(int i = 0; i < m_xValuesUNCluster.count(); ++i)
            {
                m_clusterseries[2]->append(QPointF(m_xValuesUNCluster.at(i), m_yValuesUNCluster.at(i)));
            }
        }
    }

 //add series to the chart
    for(int i = 0; i < CLUSTERSERIESCOUNT; ++i)
    {
        m_chart->addSeries(m_clusterseries[i]);
        m_clusterseries[i]->attachAxis(m_axisX);
        m_clusterseries[i]->attachAxis(m_axisY);
    }
```

This is how am adding points and it looks as below.
[image]

on Clicking each point, I want that to color with a selected color.

```
void MyView::onClickedClusterScatterObject(const QPointF& point)
{
  //color the selected cluster
  QPointF p =  m_chart->mapToPosition(point);
  QGraphicsItem *it = itemAt(mapFromScene(p));
  it->setTransformOriginPoint(it->boundingRect().center());
//the below colors the whole series
//QGraphicsColorizeEffect* effect = new QGraphicsColorizeEffect(this);
//effect->setColor(QColor(m_CRLTColor));
//it->setGraphicsEffect(effect);

 QScatterSeries* series = qobject_cast<QScatterSeries*>(sender());
 qInfo()<<__FUNCTION__<<sender()<<series->markerShape();
 if(QGraphicsRectItem *rect = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsRectItem*>(it))
{
    rect->setBrush(QColor(m_CRLTColor));
}
 m_mainScene->update();
}
```

With above code, am able to color the selected points, **only the Yellow series[ie, m_clusterseries[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBxxp.png)]**.

[image]

But on, **clicking the Blue series points[ie, m_clusterseries[0]], it fails in the qgraphicsitem_cast(it) line.
and rect->setBrush(color) doesn't execute**.
Why so? what wrong am doing?

Another issue, after new data is received, I clear the old series and perform the same initialization steps again. After the the nothing works, ie, the graphicsitem_cast fails for the yellow series also.

QGraphicsColorizeEffect code, colors the whole series, and some unexpected things, like on clicking the blue points, the yellow series is getting colored.

[image]

Any suggestion to color individual points of a qscatterseries is appreciated.